# MAMP localhost cannot connect

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, localhost, mamp

I'm a complete novice at web deving (literally just started yesterday so please explain your answers like you were talking to a 5 year old haha) and I'm setting up MAMP following along the steps on this site: https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/14/install-wordpress-mac/

I followed everything to a tee till I got to step 10. When I search localhost:8888/(insert folder name in my root folder) on my URL bar. I get "cannot connect to server."

I've googled this problem and tried all the solutions I found (here on stack overflow and others) but still nothing works. Can anyone help me?

I'm using macOS Sierra and MAMP ver 4.0.6

Comment: What happens when you go to localhost:8888 without the folder path?

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting http://localhost:8888/ and see what happens ... if there is nothing there then there is a problem with your apache configuration. Make sure the apache service was started from within the MAMP app.

**if you type the following in your terminal app:**

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl restart
```

it will output any issues or misconfiguration you may have.

Also, if you want you can give [PilotKit](https://pilotkit.co) a try, PilotKit is a
Super-easy local site development app, it launches and creates sites locally with one click, it support Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal and static sites generator plus it comes with a lot of functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

**Installation step of wordpress:**

Step - 1 : download a wordpress from wordpress website.

Step - 2 : Extract wordpress and move this extracted folder into a MAMP/htdocs folder.

Step - 3 : Next we’ll go into our MAMP start page, PHPMyAdmin, then Databases and create a database (I’ll name it “database”). Go to “localhost:8888/database/installer.php and fill in the following information.

Step - 4 : After selecting “Run Deployment”, on the following page select “Run Update”. At last, we can go to our local website at “localhost:8888/site”!

**Some cases that makes your site is not reachable**

- If you are not sure with port.It's better to check url with open a start page.
- Check you server and database working properly by creating simple file.for example.
- make sure you have database before install wordpress.If any then goto database and check wp_option table.Cross verify your `home_url` and `site_url`.